# DataTable server side processing not working with Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, datatables

I added an AJAX request for my DataTables. It works fine. But when I add `"serverSide": true` DataTables shows nothing.

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tableProduct = $('#example2').DataTable({"bInfo": false
                , "bLengthChange": false
                , "bSort": false
                , "oLanguage": {"sZeroRecords": "", "sEmptyTable": ""}
                , "processing": true
                ,  serverSide: true
                , ajax : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProduct'
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProduct',
                success: function (result) {
                    var jString = JSON.stringify(result);
                    var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);
                    for (var x = 0; x < jdata.length; x++) {
                        var td1 = jdata[x].serialNo;
                        var td2 = jdata[x].slsiUnit;
                        var td3 = jdata[x].itemDesc;
                        var td4 = jdata[x].slsNo;
                        var td5 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                        var td6 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                        var td7 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                        tableProduct.row.add([td1, td2, td3, td4, td5, td6, td7]).draw(true);
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for server-side processing not working is the **draw** variable (each page of data referred to as a **draw** in DataTables terminology) not being returned as it was set in the request. DataTables uses **draw** to keep a draw count, so this is an important parameter.

See [server-side usage](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for checking parameters that are being send by the DataTables to server and what JSON data it expects to be returned to it.

---

Besides this in your code you are again making a separate ajax request to same url and then generating the table which seems to be off way, because DataTables takes care of this. You only have to send [data in acceptable format](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Data-source-types).

Comment: How to fix my cord...can you help me